# How to get the SSL key of a https:// C# HttpWebRequest? (similar to browser environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE)

Tags: c#, ssl, https, httpwebrequest

Currently I am working on a custom HTTP publisher for the Peach Fuzzing framework.

In order to determine if the server responed in an unusual way I need to examine the decrypted incoming / outgoing packages with Wireshark (or the PcapMonitor that is included in the Peach Framework) - to do that I need the SSL keys that are being generated by the C# HttpWebRequest (similar to the content of the [SSLKEYLOGFILE](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets/16415/)) since I am trying to fuzz an SSL protected RESTful webservice.

If it is not possible to get the keys or if it is very difficult - is there any other way to see the raw HTTP request / response?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a bit disappointing that there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to get the decrypted packages:

1. Create a loopback interface that can be monitored with Wireshark
2. Create a reverse proxy (I used nginx) and redirect all traffic from "localhost" to the target URL (https://)
3. Tell your application not to send the requests to target (https://) but to localhost (http://localhost/)
4. Start listening on  the loopback interface and start your application

Hope this is helpful for somebody in a similar situation

Comment: Sounds like an interesting solution, but it's probably missing some 'nginx' instructions to make it easily useful / less daunting at face-value.  And are you proxing HTTP to HTTPS?